# What is a better way to send data updates out to clients in .net?

Tags: .net, wcf, communication, remoting, message-queue

When a user updates some data in our .net application our server sends updates out to interested clients telling them that this data has updated. Currently each client is also a server (ie. they listen on a port) the server keeps track of which clients are logged in and sends them update messages via remoting.

This works well but has potential problems as firewalls must be configured to allow access to client PCs.

There are a few ways I see to get around this but each have their drawbacks. I am currently investigating wcf or a queueing system like msmq, however I don't have any experience with these and the learning curve seems steep. Other options I have in mind are:

- Geting clients to call a server method that does not return until a message comes in -  potential problems with timeouts, disconnections, etc?
- Change to WCF and use callbacks - not sure if this requires the client to be an endpoint?
- Use a timer and check for messages every few seconds - potential to flood the network

Is there some other way this could be implemented? I see this as a problem that has probably already be solved so hopefully implementation will be straightforward. Ideally no connected client should miss a message and this could be used for other types of updates - eg. progress updates of server jobs, etc.

Comment: (I'm not sure this can be considered a programming question.) I recommend you seriously consider WCF as the learning curve probably isn't as bad as you fear. There are plenty of tutorials out there and you can get up and running quite quickly. IICDIAC!

Answer (score 1):

If clients are intermittently connected, but still need to receive an update message then MSMQ is pretty straight forward.

Answer (score 1):

WCF and callbacks work well in this senario.  See answer to this not dissimilar question:[WCF - client callback recommended?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7992025/wcf-client-callback-recommended/7993207#7993207)  WCF is rather flexible interms of transport and connection configuration (timeouts etc).

Answer (score -3):

You probably want to take a look at [ClickOnce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ClickOnce).

Here's an article on selecting a ClickOnce update strategy: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s22azw1e.aspx

Comment: The question seems to be about updating DATA, not the client app itself

Comment: My bad, missed the key word there